# Traefik recreat all ACME certificate at each restart

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm currently configuring Traefik with Let's encrypt.
But I have an issue : Each time I restart the container, Traefik regenerate all certificate. Even those already in the acme.json file :(.

But my server do automatic restart sometimes. So, within a day, Let's encrypt does not want to give me more certificates.

Do any way exist to rsolve this issue ? :(

My docker-compose.yml file :

```
services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik:alpine
        restart: always
        container_name: traefik
        networks:
            - default
            - traefik_proxy
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "8000:8080"
        volumes:
            # traefik configuration files
            - ${TRAEFIK_CONTAINERS_CONFIG_DIR}/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
            - ${TRAEFIK_CONTAINERS_CONFIG_DIR}/acme.json:/acme.json
            - ${TRAEFIK_CONTAINERS_CONFIG_DIR}/log:/var/log/traefik/
            - ${TRAEFIK_CONTAINERS_CONFIG_DIR}/shared:/shared/

            # Docker
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

            # We have to link the authentification dir to use the differents .htpasswd
            - ${AUTHENTIFICATION_FILES_DIRECTORY}:/htpasswd/
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:reverse.${DOMAIN_NAME}"

            - "traefik.port=8080"

            - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic.usersFile=${TRAEFIK_DEFAULT_AUTHENTIFICATION_FILE}"
            - "traefik.tags=proxy"

            - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
```